# Web scraping in react-native ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native

I am building an iOS app with react-native and looking to do some web scraping. From my understanding traditional npm packages don't work because they rely on Node.js. I know there are Objective-C/Swift libraries for web scraping but I don't understand how I would integrate those into a react-native component.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get information from a website (web scraping) in react-native?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question. Architecturally, it might be a good idea to consider building a service which can provide the scraped data via an API. The more processing power the client requires (the heavier the client-side code), the more likely you are to run into lagging / stuttering issues in the app. Phones have come a long way, but still can't match a server's power.

If you want to press ahead, I would advise using the [browserified](http://browserify.org/) version of [Cheerio.js](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). Basically, browserify lets you take code written for node, and use it in a browser environment. You would need to test it in JS Core on IOS, but there's a good chance everything will work.

One other option is using jQuery's load function or the fetch api included in React Native to make the call to the site (you don't have to worry about CORS), and parse the result manually.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I just built an API that did the web scraping. Thanks for the insight!